# How to propertly delete Stings from array in JS?

Tags: javascript, loops

So i'm trying to write a function that deletes all the strings from array.

It works, but deletes only half of them, why?

```
let list = [1,2,'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];


function filter_list(l) {
    for (let i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        if(typeof l[i] === 'string') {
            l.splice(l.indexOf(l[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(l)
}

filter_list(list)
```

Comment: Use `filter` based on the `typeof` the value.

Comment: using your `split` method, your index `i` becomes desynced from the index you're trying to access because you're deleting stuff while you're iterating over the same stuff. So for example if `i` is 3, and you're checking if you should delete the 4th element, and you DO delete it, then the next element moves down to index 3, but your next iteration starts at 4 and you've skipped one. The way to deal with this is to iterate backwards

Comment: Although really the ideal way to do it is `array.filter()`, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return a filtered subset Array, and [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check the operand type:

```js
const list = [1,2,'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const nums = list.filter(x => typeof x !== "string"); 
console.log(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [1,2,'a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const nums = list.filter(i => typeof i !== "string"); 
console.log(nums)
```

This checks each element and excludes those of type string.